# How to access remotely a dockerised database container in Ubuntu OS?

Tags: mysql, docker, ubuntu

**Current Situation :**
In my company we are using a windows server, in which we have installed Docker Quickstart Terminal. We have made a mysql-container and made a DB inside. We access the DB with python apps in **remote** pcs by using the server's IP in the code (host argument):

`connx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='somepass', host='192.XXX.XX.XX', port=3306,               database='db_name', auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')`

but we used port-forward in the server-side to access the dockerised DB, thus the packets are forwarded to 192.168.99.100 (default docker IP)

**Future Situation**:
The company has decided to change the server and use Ubuntu instead (v18.04 i think). Unfortunately i have very little experience with linux and could not find a simple answer as the following online :

'Which IP should we use on the host argument above ?' 
Docker installation on linux does not seem to install a VM, so will the new server's IP be enough to access the dockerised IP remotely ?

PS : we will probably do a 'docker run  -p 3306:3306 mysql:latest' command on the server to expose the ports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access the database the say way you were able to access in Windows Server, i.e., using the IP of the Ubuntu host machine and port forwarding the containerized database port with the host port.

Comment: thanks for the answer, is the :

```docker run -p 3306:3306 mysql:latest``` command enough ? or should i google how to do port forward in ubuntu ?

Comment: ok thanks a lot for your time ! i will try it when the time comes.